# javac issues compiling source code

Tags: java, linux, error-handling, compiler-errors, javac

I'm trying to compile a Java source code with `javac` in a Linux terminal allocated in a machine that **I have not permission to modify its Java version**. Now it has 1.7.0_111 version, and the result I obtained is:

[image]

How can I manage to compile my code? Is there any manner to compile my source code using compatibility mode?

Thank you.

Comment: Please copy and paste all the text from the terminal into the question - only the text is relevant, and it's *much* easier to see text when it's posted *as* text.

Comment: It seems you're trying to make an older version of `java` to run a program compiled by a much newer `javac` compiler. If you have the source, you can compile it with the `--source` and `--target` parameters to comply with the version you will run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is actually compiled with JDK 8 and you want to execute it with Java 7.
You cannot.

If you code doesn't use specificities from Java 8, you could compile it with as Java target, the Java 7 version.

For example :

```
javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7  ...
```

Otherwise you are stuck.